# How do I fix a chamberlain garage door opener that won't work due to light circuit interference

Tags: garage-door-opener

My Chamberlain model 9902 garage door opener remotes only work if the light circuit is turned off using the hardwired key pad. It did not matter whether I used an LED, and CF or an incandescent, or even if the light bulb socket was empty. The remotes only work if the light circuit is turned off manually, and then it works every time. Distance does not matter. Extending antenna didn't matter. Same with new remotes. Is there a way to switch out or disable the internal light circuit board?

Comment: How old is this opener? If it's still under warranty, you fix it by calling Chamberlain.